# Details of a specific table entry in a Grails App

Tags: database, postgresql, grails, groovy

So I've been messing around with grails lately and I've been making a Grails CRUD sort of application. I've been using a db on postgres for my data so no domain classes are made. Only services,controllers and views are used.

Inside the main index page a user can see his Songlist and :

1.Create a new song to add into the db (easy to do)
2. View the details of a specific song.
3. Edit a song
4. Delete a song

[image: Here is a sample pic.]

I am trying to do the details functionality but my brain is stuck on the way of how to get the specific songs id in order to render another gsp with the song's details

Comment: But you are already rendering the ID from the songs in the table. You can use a g:link that points to the show method in the controller with the specific ID and render his details.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment about use a g:link with the id attribute from the domain object.

```
<g:link role="button" class="btn btn-success" action="show" id="${yourInstance.id}">Detail</g:link>
```

Then on the Controller:

```
def show(YourDomain yourInstance) {}
```

Grails will lookup the Instance based on the ID passed from the g:link.

Using the scaffolding should generate something like the above.

Comment: played around a bit and found the solution, relative to your answer. thanks!